# MVC 4 Email sending

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, smtp

im trying to do password recovery thingy, using email. Im using WebMail.Send function, but it ends out with timeout, i've got problem figuring out why.

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 465;
WebMail.Send(to:email, subject:"Password Reset", body:"Your password reset token is <a          href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" +token+ " </a> please visit " + confirmationUrl );
```

WebMail.UserName and WebMail.Password are also set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail SMTP ports are 25(SSL) or 587(TLS),please try to use one of these ports.465(SSL) may give problem sometime.

Comment: that helped i guess, now i've got "5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first."